# server-side disconnection of user

Tags: asp.net

I manage Disabled and CanConnect properties for the users of a web site. I'm looking for a good way to "cut" a user connection if one of the cited properties is not in the good state.

Actually I check the user in my master layout and call FormsAuthentication.SignOut() when needed. But this does not satisfy me. My next try will be to override the Authorize filter (which is not recommanded it seems).

What I'm looking for is a way to reset session(s) of a specific user to disable (at the sevrer-side) all his living cookies (I used to do that with php/apache). So, even if the user has a living connection when Disabled becomes true, the next query will lead him to the connection page.

Comment: I don't think you can guarantee deletion of cookies, unless you wrote the user's browser too! What is wrong with FormsAuthentication.SignOut()? Might Session.Clear() do something approximating what you want? (or was it Session.Abandon()?)

Comment: well, I don't want to guarantee deletion of cookies at the browser side, but the deletion of the related data at server side: Something like purge session for user but being connected as another admin user.

Comment: An admin user? Like, Urist McUser is using the system, and he requires technical assistance, so he temporarily cedes control of his PC to Tom Techie?

Comment: no, McUser, employed by WorldCompany, uses the system and an admin receive a call of WorldCompany boss requesting the immediate cancelation of mcUser access

Comment: Ah, I see. I'd expect FormsAuthentication.SignOut() or Session.Abandon() to work, then - what problem are you having with the former?

Comment: well in this case the cancelation is not strictly immediate, one should wait McUser to try to use the application once more.

Comment: Hmm, so you're saying you want to not only prevent him from interacting with the site, but also from viewing whatever's already on his screen? Don't think that's really possible - sure, you could use a Javascript callback to query the user's status and kick him, but he could just disable Javascript, or even save off the HTML that's in his browser beforehand!